# KIVY - bind function via class property?

Tags: python, kivy

If you run this code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0
<MyGrid>:
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        text: 'open popup'
        on_release: root.openPopup()
<TestClass>
    size_hint: 0.7, 0.7
    Button:
        id: thisButton
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        text: root.message
        on_release: root.thisOne()
        on_release: root.closeme()
''')

class TestClass(Popup):
    message = StringProperty('')
    buttonFunction = ObjectProperty(None)

    def closeme(self):
        self.dismiss()
    def thisOne(self):
        print('success')

class MyGrid(FloatLayout):
    def openPopup(self):
        y = TestClass(message = 'test text')
        y.open()

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

You will see I can send text to the Button via class property(TestClass.message).
But if you run the code below.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0
<MyGrid>:
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint_x: {'center_x': 0.5}
        text: 'open popup'
        on_release: root.openPopup()
<TestClass>
    # thisButton: thisButton
    size_hint: 0.7, 0.7
    Button:
        id: thisButton
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
        text: root.message
        # text: 'OK'
        on_release: root.buttonFunction()
''')

class TestClass(Popup):
    message = StringProperty('')
    buttonFunction = ObjectProperty(None)

    def closeme(self):
        self.dismiss()

    def thisOne(self):
        print('success')

class MyGrid(FloatLayout):

    def openPopup(self):
        y = TestClass(message = 'test text', buttonFunction = TestClass.closeme())
        y.open()

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):

        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

I don't know if I can specify button function to the button via class property. The error is that 'TypeError: closeme() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self''
Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `closeme()` method of the instance of `TestClass` that you are creating. So, you can change your `openPopup()` method slightly:

```
def openPopup(self):
    y = TestClass(message = 'test text')
    y.buttonFunction = y.closeme
    y.open()
```

Now, the `buttonFunction` refers to the `closeme()` method of the `TestClass` instance.

Another way is to take advantage of the `ObjectProperty` in `kv`. If you change the `TestClass` to set the `buttonfunction` in an `__init__()` method:

```
class TestClass(Popup):
    message = StringProperty('')
    buttonFunction = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # set the buttonfunction
        self.buttonFunction = self.closeme
```

Then, your `openPopup()` method can just be:

```
def openPopup(self):
    y = TestClass(message = 'test text')
    y.open()
```

Comment: hi @John Anderson , the first solution is what i am look for. Since I want to do this in another class. Thanks a lot. I ever tried 'y.buttonFunction = y.closeme()', It doesn't work. It's pretty close.

Comment: The reason that `y.buttonFunction = y.closeme()` doesn't work is that you are executing the `closeme()` method and assigning its return value (which is `None`) to the `buttonFunction`.